# How to include .asg macros from another assembly file (.asm)

Tags: assembly, msp430

I'm programming an MSP 430 in assembly and I'd like to include some `.asg` macros from another file in the same project.  I know that some `.word`elements are being included using `.def` and `.ref` but if I use `.include` on the whole file I get the error that some elements are defined twice.  How can I include a section of just `.asg` macros?

Comment: What you're asking for seems to be rather unreal. Why don't you just put `.asg` macros into a separate file and include it to both files you're using?

Comment: I just figured that if other parts of the file I'm using are already included (I didn't make the original file myself) then I would be able to include the other parts in a similar way.

Comment: Well, there isn't much to add, but remember it's a good practice to use defines to check whether you already have included a file or not.